# How to add/update/delete data form multi table with vba access

Tags: vba, ms-access, recordset

I have 4 table:

1. table OrderA link external data from textfile
2. table OrderB link external data from textfile
3. table OrderDetail is merge 2 table OrderA and OrderB (OrderA and append OrderB)
4. table RecTable

The data in Tables 1 and 2 change. If the data are added to Tables 1 and 2: Add to Table 3 as well.

If data in Tables 1 and 2 are updated, Tables 3 will also be updated.

If data is deleted from Tables 1 and 2, it is removed from Table 3 and added to Table 4.

ِDlookup is low for this work. How can I do this with recordset?

edit:
I write this code but not work in delete.

> runtime error 3135
>       Syntax error in JOIN opration.

```
Dim strSqlAddtoHazf As String
Dim strFindDelete As String    
Dim rsOrderHazf As DAO.Recordset
   strFindDelete = "SELECT IDPhotoO ,  jensO , vazeiatO , dateaddO ,  
 customeridO , orderidO , usernameO , tedadO , FileNameO   FROM  
 OrderDetail  LEFT JOIN RataPhotoOrderDetail ON (OrderDetail.IDPhotoO =  
 RataPhotoOrderDetail.id) WHERE (RataPhotoOrderDetail.id Is Null and  
 OrderDetail.IDGharardadO Is Null);"    
 strSqlAddtoHazf = " insert into OrderHazf (IDPhotoH ,  jensH , vazeiatH ,  
dateaddH , customeridH , orderidH , usernameH , tedadH , FileNameH ) " &  
strFindDelete
 DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL strSqlAddtoHazf
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
 strFindDelete = "SELECT IDPhotoO ,  jensO , vazeiatO , dateaddO , customeridO , orderidO , usernameO , tedadO , FileNameO   FROM OrderDetai  LEFT JOIN OrderHazf ON (OrderDetail.IDPhotoO = orderHazf.IDPhotoH) WHERE (Orderhazf.IDPhotoH Is Null and OrderDetail.IDGharardadO Is Null);"
Set rsOrderHazf = CurrentDb().OpenRecordset(strFindDelete)

Do Until rsOrderHazf.EOF()

rsOrderHazf.Delete

Loop
```

'
'''

Answer (score 0):

i will suggest you place all the queries in a macro ,with each query in a macro line,
place them in the order that you want the query to run, with the first query been at the top most line.
e.g if query 1 is to run first and the result will determine the what query 2 will do then

place query 1 as the first query to be run in the macro condition, query 2 as the second query to be run, etc.

Then attach the macro name to a command button.